# Use a URL stored in a cell in an Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a spreadsheet with a list of clients in column A and in column B I have their websites. I'm using a drop down list to select a specific client which will then display various bits of data on another sheet.

I'm looking to use the Power Query tool to access their websites in excel. However I can't work out how to select the url from this list as it always asks me to type in the address rather than give it a cell to look up.

```
Column A| Column B
abc ltd | http://www.abcltd.com
def ltd | http://www.defltd.com
ghi ltd | http://www.ghiltd.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly connect to a web page with `Web.Contents` and then read the content with something like `Web.Page` or `Excel.Workbook`. If your table is named `Table`, then you can add a column which connects to the web site like this:

`= Table.AddColumn(Table, each Web.Page(Web.Contents([Column B]))`

You will need to define privacy levels for the websites. If you trust all of the websites in the column, you can also disable privacy levels for the workbook.